# How to use Regular Expression for whole numbers with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

As I've tried with the code below but it did not work. I would like to use Regular Expression for **only whole numbers**.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(tbColumn.Text, @"^[0-9]") == true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("true");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("false");
}
```

With my code:

```
0 --> true
1 --> true
9 --> true
10 --> false (it must be true)
100 --> false (it must be true)
```

For example:

```
0 --> true
1 --> true
100 --> true
34343 --> true
0.5 --> false
1.42 --> false
1,2 --> false
a1 --> false
a --> false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place a [quantifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx) after your character class and add the end of string `$` anchor to the regex.

```
^[0-9]+$
```

The `+` quantifier matches the preceding token "one or more" times.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What is the difference between `+$` vs `$`?